# Взаимодействие с файлом в ресурсах проекта

Tags: c#

Есть файл `config.ini` (в ресурсах) - как с ним взаимодействовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: byte[] file = Properties.Resources.<имя файла>;

Comment: какой build action выставлен в свойствах у config.ini?

Comment: @PashaPash - я не знаю - где выставить?

Comment: @rdorn неявное преобразование byte[] to string

Comment: @PashaPash а все - внедренный ресурс

Comment: @Сергей если на код от rdorn выдает именно такую ошибку - то или работайте с данными как со строкой (вам же вроде в файл надо записать - File.WriteAllText), или сконвертируйте в байты через Encoding.GetBytes

Comment: @PashaPash получаю ошибку error TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' from assembly

Comment: если вы добавляли его как текстовый файл, то замените byte[] на string

Comment: @Сергей на записи в файл? покажите весь код.

Comment: писать в ресурсы нельзя, они только для чтения. По предыдущему вопросу вам было нужно хранить эталонные файлы вроде.

Comment: @PashaPash https://pastebin.com/3HDgH1aG

Comment: а зачем вы задвоили `/`, он же не требует экранирования, экранировать надо ` \\ `? или я что-то упустил?

Comment: @rdorn у меня так работает - только говорю же ошибка то другая - error TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' from assembly

Comment: на чем ошибка: на записи или на получении из ресурсов? Добавьте воспроизводящий ошибку код и текст ошибки в вопрос, вместо скрина, от которого никакой.пользы.

Comment: @rdorn ошибка появляется,когда исполняется код

Comment: string file = Properties.Resources.config;
                File.WriteAllText(server.datadir + "cfg//config.ini", file);

Comment: путь проверяйте. соберите полный путь в отдельной переменной, и проверьте что там все корректно. И еще раз: / не требует экранирования. а задвоенный может вызывать ошибку при определении конечной точки и типа ресурса

Comment: скорее всего падает  `new GameObject(bootstrap.GetType().FullName).AddComponent(bootstrap.GetType());`, и это не имеет отношения к вопросу :)

Comment: @PashaPash - как раз тут все работает - ошибка появляется тут => string file = Properties.Resources.config

Comment: Стоп. А версия установленного на сервере .NET Framework совпадает с установленной в настройках проекта? Если проект собирается для более старшей версии, то естественно он не запустится, если установлена более младшая. причем разные проекты и библиотеки в одном солюшене могут требовать разные версии, необходимо ориентироваться на самую старшую из них

Answer (score 2):

Правой кнопкой на `config.ini` -> `propertys(свойства)`

В окне `build action(действия при сборке)`->`Embedded Resource (внедренный ресурс)`

Код возвращающий `config.ini`, т.е. его содержимое в качестве `Stream'

```
public static Stream GetResourceStream(string EndsWithKey, bool equals = false)
{
  try
  {
    Assembly assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string key = assm.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(x => equals ? x.Equals(EndsWithKey) : x.EndsWith(EndsWithKey));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((key ?? "").Trim()))
        return assm.GetManifestResourceStream(key);
    //Если ресурс может находиться также и в подключаемых dll, то необходим следующий блок
    foreach (Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
    { 
      key = a.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(x => equals ? x.Equals(EndsWithKey) : x.EndsWith(EndsWithKey));
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((key ?? "").Trim()))
        return a.GetManifestResourceStream(key);
    }
  }
  catch
  {
  }
  return null;
}
```

где то в программе

```
using (Stream configini = GetResourceStream("Config.ini", false)) 
{
  ..
}
```

или если знаете полный путь к нему в проекте

```
using (Stream configini = GetResourceStream("folder1.folder2.Config.ini", true)) 
{
  ..
}
```

**Важно!**

- Путь к файлу указывается через точку
- Регистр важен.

Comment: Есть еще более простой способ подключения ресурсов через свойства проекта (Properties/Resources), судя по раскладке файлов и по наличию Properties.Resources.config - именно его и использовал топикастер. если он сделает так, как у вы предлагаете - он получит файл в ресурсах дважды, в разном виде.

Comment: Ну это на его выбор, я предложил вариант, использующийся у меня в проектах, иногда мне приходится вытаскивать ресурсы из dll...